# Using preventDefault() and defaultPrevented with custom events in javascript

Tags: javascript, events

When firing a custom event, I want to allow the consumer of that event to prevent a default action:

```js
var foo = new CustomEvent('foo');
var result = document.dispatchEvent(foo);
if (!result.defaultPrevented) {
  // perform the default action
}
```

And the event handler:

```js
document.addEventListener('foo', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

This doesn't seem to work as expected. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOxMbX?editors=001

What am I missing?

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) indicates that dispatchEvent returns a boolean indicating whether preventDefault was called, not an object with a defaultPrevented property.  In other words, check `result`, not `result.defaultPrevented`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That was it. I'm actually troubleshooting this as part of a different js framework, Polymer, which returns the event object instead of a boolean in its `fire()` method. But, I wanted to understand how it worked in vanilla JS before I looked further into it.